# Is there a way to optimise an SMR hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Seagate Backup Plus hard drive, and I think I'm running into the issues of SMR:  I've nearly filled the drive up. and this is after already deleting large chunks of data off it. I'm now copying another large lot of files to it, and it keeps alternating between decent transfer rates (of around 50MB/s) and terrible rates (128KB/s)

Assuming SMR read|modify|write problems are the issue here, is there some process I can run (like a 'defrag') while I'm not using the drive, to optimise it so that it writes quickly when I do need to use it.

I'm imagining something like a defrag - which leaves large contiguous chunks of free space, and then informing the drive that those chunks are free (such that it knows it doesn't need to read|modify|write, it can just write over whats there).

All this is just a guess based off the general theory of SMR and the fact that sequential writes are best.

Can I just run a normal defrag?

Comment: IIRC you need to let the drive sit idle for however long it takes.

Comment: Try to TRIM it. Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just run a normal defrag. On a large SMR drive, however, a full defrag will take an unfeasibly long time. If you are seeing 128KB/s when it does internal transfers from the staging area to the target location, you can expect the defrag to run at 128KB/s after the first few GB. That works out at about 100 days per terabyte to defrag.

There is, unfortunately, no practical solution to this, if you need to perform sustained writes that are larger than the disk's internal staging area.

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to get a second drive, and copy all the data across. This may take a long time but the writes should all be defragmented. Once that's done (and verified!) you can then reformat and trim the old drive. This should mark everything as blank (aside from the file allocation tables / superblocks) and be ready for the next time you need to copy the data across.

Comment: If you're going to get a second drive, just make sure it's CMR and you'll be done after the "copy all the data across" step ;)

Comment: @gronostaj .. and sell the first one to recoup some of the money you spent on the second one!